# What are some good mobile web app frameworks for touch events?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html

Are their any good mobile web app frameworks for touch events?

Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) would be one of my favorites

It supports all major browsers including Android.

Comment: Yea this looks good, Sencha touch seems to work better but the licensing looks l

Comment: @float well sometimes you can't have it all hehe... I'm glad technically it looks good for your device and application :)